# Trigger Elementor Popup from a Select element

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, elementor

I'm trying to open a specific Elementor popup when someone is changing the value of a Select element.

The code is working perfectly on Mac (on Safari, Chrome and Opera), but not on Windows (the popup starts to open and then closes immediately).

Here is my code:

```
<select name="forma" id="forma">
    <option value="">Je veux devenir...</option>
 <option value="185">Boucher(ère)</option>
 <option value="221">Boulanger(ère)</option>
 <option value="224">Charcutier(ère)</option>
</select>

<script>
jQuery('#forma').on('change', function() {
    elementorProFrontend.modules.popup.showPopup( { id: this.value } );
});
</script>
```

=> On Mac everything works fine (all browsers)
=> On Windows the popup starts to open and the closes immediately...

Thanks for your help!
Martial